# Jquery addition instead of conacatination

Tags: jquery, addition

I want to add the commision if the special commision is having any value else i want to set the commision to 2%% by default if user leave that field blank when i do not put any value the calculation is correct but when  i put any value say 100 then the value is concatinated to the commision instead of addition please tell me what is the error in my code?

Here is my function :

```
$('body').delegate('.quantity,.price,.discount,.spl', 'keyup', function () {
        var tr = $(this).parent().parent();

        var qty = tr.find('.quantity').val();
        var price = tr.find('.price').val();

         var special_commision = 2/100; 


         if($('.spl').val()){
            var special_commision = parseInt($('.spl').val()) +  special_commision ;
         }

        var dis = tr.find('.discount').val();
        var amt = (qty * price) - (qty * price * dis) / 100;

        cal_spl = amt*special_commision;
        tr.find('.amount').val(amt);
        tr.find('.sm').val(cal_spl);


        total();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').delegate('.quantity,.price,.discount,.spl', 'keyup', function () {
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent();

    var qty =parseInt(tr.find('.quantity').val());
    var price = parseInt(tr.find('.price').val());

     var special_commision = 2/100; 


     if($('.spl').val()){
        var special_commision = parseInt($('.spl').val()) +  special_commision ;
     }

    var dis = parseInt(tr.find('.discount').val());
    var amt = (qty * price) - (qty * price * dis) / 100;

    cal_spl = amt*special_commision;
    tr.find('.amount').val(amt);
    tr.find('.sm').val(cal_spl);


    total();
});
```

> parseInt() Your tr Tag value.